# JS Переключение класса между несколькими активными элементами

Tags: javascript, slider

на странице есть блок с 5 слайдами:

```
<div class="block__slides" id="slider1">

        <div class="block__slide slide-active"></div>
        <div class="block__slide slide-active"></div>
        <div class="block__slide slide-active"></div>
        <div class="block__slide "></div>
        <div class="block__slide "></div>

</div>
```

Только три из них являются активными.

также есть две кнопки:

```
 <button class="block__control" id="left-slider-button"></button>
 <button class="block__control" id="right-slider-button"></button>
```

как сделать код который будет при клике на кнопку вправо :

- искать первый элемент block__slides
- убирать у него класс slide__active
- искать ближайший элемент после слайда с классом slide__active и добавлять ему этот класс (так чтобы отображалось всегда три слайда)
- если это последний слайд у родителя с классом slide__active то он должен переставлять его снова на первый элемент чтобы получался круг

И аналогичную функцию для кнопки влево.

вообще я верно понимаю реализацию этого процесса?

Буду благодарен за помощь с примерами кода.

Comment: Не хотите попробовать сами?

Comment: я этим и занимаюсь =)

Comment: Из вопроса этого не видно.

Comment: Извини, это не специально =)

Comment: Покажите ваш код. Что уже сделали, что не получается.

Comment: в том то и проблема, что мой мозг даже не понимает что нужно сначала сделать

Comment: У тебя же есть пример с одним активным, что мешает применить тот же подход для нескольких?

Answer (score 2):

Через "пятое колено", конечно... Но, как вариант:

```js
var aSlides, mSlides = [];
window.onload = function() {
  
  aSlides = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('slider1').querySelectorAll('.block__slide'));
  aSlides.forEach(function(el) {
    mSlides.push((el.classList.contains('slide-active')) ? '1' : '0');
  });

  document.querySelector('div.block__controls').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    if (ev.target.id == 'left-slider-button') { fShiftSlides(false); }
    if (ev.target.id == 'right-slider-button') { fShiftSlides(true); }
  });
}

function fShiftSlides(bDirection) {
  if (bDirection) { mSlides.unshift(mSlides.pop()); } 
  else { mSlides.push(mSlides.shift()); }

  aSlides.forEach(function(el, index) {
    if (mSlides[index] == '1') { el.classList.add('slide-active'); } 
    else { el.classList.remove('slide-active'); }
  });
}
```

```css
.block__slides,
.block__controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.block__slide {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #090;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
.slide-active {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 0%;
}

.block__control {
  height: 25px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block__slides" id="slider1">
  <div class="block__slide slide-active">1</div>
  <div class="block__slide slide-active">2</div>
  <div class="block__slide slide-active">3</div>
  <div class="block__slide ">4</div>
  <div class="block__slide ">5</div>
</div>
<div class="block__controls">
  <button class="block__control" id="left-slider-button">&lt;</button>
  <button class="block__control" id="right-slider-button">&gt;</button>
</div>
```

*Количество блоков может быть любым.*

---

Вариант с таймером:

```js
var tSlides, aSlides, mSlides = [];
window.onload = function() {
  
  aSlides = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('slider1').querySelectorAll('.block__slide'));
  aSlides.forEach(function(el) {
    mSlides.push((el.classList.contains('slide-active')) ? '1' : '0');
  });

  document.querySelector('div.block__controls').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    if (ev.target.id == 'left-slider-button') { clearInterval(tSlides); fShiftSlides(false); }
    if (ev.target.id == 'right-slider-button') { clearInterval(tSlides); fShiftSlides(true); }
    if (document.getElementById('timer-slider-button').checked) {
      tSlides = setInterval(function() { fShiftSlides(true); }, 2000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(tSlides);
    }
  });
}

function fShiftSlides(bDirection) {
  if (bDirection) { mSlides.unshift(mSlides.pop()); } 
  else { mSlides.push(mSlides.shift()); }

  aSlides.forEach(function(el, index) {
    if (mSlides[index] == '1') { el.classList.add('slide-active'); } 
    else { el.classList.remove('slide-active'); }
  });
}
```

```css
.block__slides,
.block__controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.block__slide {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #090;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
.slide-active {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 0%;
}

.block__control {
  height: 25px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block__slides" id="slider1">
  <div class="block__slide slide-active">1</div>
  <div class="block__slide slide-active">2</div>
  <div class="block__slide slide-active">3</div>
  <div class="block__slide ">4</div>
  <div class="block__slide ">5</div>
</div>
<div class="block__controls">
  <button class="block__control" id="left-slider-button">&lt;</button>
  <input type="checkbox" class="block__control" id="timer-slider-button">
  <button class="block__control" id="right-slider-button">&gt;</button>
</div>
```

---

Вариант для нескольких слайдеров и анимацией таймера:

```js
'use strict';
window.onload = function() {
  /* Находим и перебираем все слайдеры на странице */
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.block__slider')).forEach(function(elSlider) {
    // Временный массив для начального состояния слайдов
    let mSlides = [];
    /* Находим и перебираем все слайды в конкретном блоке слайдов */
    Array.prototype.slice.call(elSlider.querySelectorAll('.block__slide')).forEach(function(elSlide) {
      // Заносим в массив начальное состояние слайдов
      mSlides.push((elSlide.classList.contains('slide-active')) ? '1' : '0');
    });
    // Сохраняем значения массива в пользовательском атрибуте
    elSlider.setAttribute('data-shift', mSlides.join(''));
    /* Делегируем обработчик клика блоку с кнопками */
    elSlider.querySelector('div.block__controls').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
      // Если нажата левая кнопка
      if (ev.target.classList.contains('left-slider-button')) {
        // Останавливаем таймер
        clearInterval(this.tSlides);
        // Удаляем анимацию таймера
        this.classList.remove('timer-active');
        // Вызываем функцию сдвига
        fShiftSlides(this.parentElement, false);
      }
      // Если нажата правая кнопка
      if (ev.target.classList.contains('right-slider-button')) {
        clearInterval(this.tSlides);
        this.classList.remove('timer-active');
        fShiftSlides(this.parentElement, true);
      }
      // Если отмечен таймер
      if (this.querySelector('.timer-slider-button').checked) {
        // Запускаем таймер с функцией сдвига
        this.tSlides = setInterval(fShiftSlides, 2500, this.parentElement, true);
        // Добавляем анимацию таймера
        this.classList.add('timer-active');
      } else {
        clearInterval(this.tSlides);
        this.classList.remove('timer-active');
      }
    });
  });
}

/* Функция сдвига и назначения классов */
function fShiftSlides(oSlider, bDirection) {
  // Временный массив состояний слайдов
  let mSlides = oSlider.getAttribute('data-shift').split('');
  // Изменяем массив в соответствии с направлением
  if (bDirection) {
    // Сдвиг вправо
    mSlides.unshift(mSlides.pop());
  } else {
    // Сдвиг влево
    mSlides.push(mSlides.shift());
  }
  /* Находим и перебираем все слайды в конкретном блоке слайдов */
  Array.prototype.slice.call(oSlider.querySelectorAll('.block__slide')).forEach(function(el, index) {
    // Изменяем классы у слайдов на основании значений массива
    if (mSlides[index] == '1') {
      el.classList.add('slide-active');
    } else {
      el.classList.remove('slide-active');
    }
  });
  // Сохраняем изменённый массив
  oSlider.setAttribute('data-shift', mSlides.join(''));
}
```

```css
.block__slides,
.block__controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.block__slide {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #090;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px -3px black;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.slide-active {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 20px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.block__control {
  height: 25px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10px 15px 15px;
}

.timer-active {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #f00, #fa0, #0a0);
  background-size: 0% 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  animation: timer 2.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes timer {
  0% { background-size: 0% 2px; }
  100% { background-size: 100% 2px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="block__slider" id="slider1">
  <div class="block__slides">
    <div class="block__slide slide-active">1</div>
    <div class="block__slide slide-active">2</div>
    <div class="block__slide slide-active">3</div>
    <div class="block__slide ">4</div>
    <div class="block__slide ">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block__controls">
    <button class="block__control left-slider-button">&lt;</button>
    <input class="block__control timer-slider-button" type="checkbox">
    <button class="block__control right-slider-button">&gt;</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block__slider" id="slider2">
  <div class="block__slides">
    <div class="block__slide slide-active">1</div>
    <div class="block__slide slide-active">2</div>
    <div class="block__slide slide-active">3</div>
    <div class="block__slide ">4</div>
    <div class="block__slide ">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block__controls">
    <button class="block__control left-slider-button">&lt;</button>
    <input class="block__control timer-slider-button" type="checkbox">
    <button class="block__control right-slider-button">&gt;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Код не большой, просто раздулся от комментариев :-)*

Comment: Большое спасибо, есть два вопроса: можно ли как то этому добавить таймер?
И если я захочу сделать две вкладки такого слайдера, нужно ли менять названия классов чтоы работали кнопки?

Comment: Сейчас если я скопирую код и вставлю второй такой же под id slider2 .
и буду переключаться между ними с помощью display flex display none, код будет работать только с первый под id slider1

Comment: Пожалуйста помоги справиться, реально 2 дня сижу и не понимаю в каком месте нужно рыть

Comment: @BigD для многократного использования на странице, нужно переписать код, чтобы все обращения к элементам были через DOM или через классы.

Comment: @BigD добавил ваши "хотелки". Дальше сами. Удачи.

Answer (score 1):

Немного переделал код @UModeL. Что бы работало для нескольких слайдеров. Нужно обернуть каждый слайдер в блок с классом .slider__holder. Так же убрал айди с кнопок и добавил классы .button-left .button-right

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var sliderHolders = [...document.querySelectorAll(".slider__holder")];
        sliderHolders.forEach(elem => init(elem));

        function init(elem) {
          var aSlides,
            mSlides = [];
          aSlides = Array.prototype.slice.call(
            elem.querySelectorAll(".block__slide")
          );
          aSlides.forEach(function(el) {
            mSlides.push(el.classList.contains("slide-active") ? "1" : "0");
          });

          elem
            .querySelector(".block__controls")
            .addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
              if (ev.target.classList.contains("button-left")) {
                fShiftSlides(false);
              }
              if (ev.target.classList.contains("button-right")) {
                fShiftSlides(true);
              }
            });

          function fShiftSlides(bDirection) {
            if (bDirection) {
              mSlides.unshift(mSlides.pop());
            } else {
              mSlides.push(mSlides.shift());
            }

            aSlides.forEach(function(el, index) {
              if (mSlides[index] == "1") {
                el.classList.add("slide-active");
              } else {
                el.classList.remove("slide-active");
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });
```

```css
.block__slides,
      .block__controls {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .block__slide {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 2px solid #090;
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        transition: 0.5s ease;
      }
      .slide-active {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        border-radius: 0%;
      }

      .block__control {
        height: 25px;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 15px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="slider__holder">
      <div class="block__slides">
        <div class="block__slide slide-active">1</div>
        <div class="block__slide slide-active">2</div>
        <div class="block__slide slide-active">3</div>
        <div class="block__slide ">4</div>
        <div class="block__slide ">5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block__controls">
        <button class="block__control button-right">
          &lt;
        </button>
        <button class="block__control button-left">
          &gt;
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__holder">
      <div class="block__slides">
        <div class="block__slide slide-active">1</div>
        <div class="block__slide slide-active">2</div>
        <div class="block__slide slide-active">3</div>
        <div class="block__slide ">4</div>
        <div class="block__slide ">5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block__controls">
        <button class="block__control button-right">
          &lt;
        </button>
        <button class="block__control button-left">
          &gt;
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```